# Python, VS Code, "package not found"

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ros2

I have a Python project opened in vs code. To be more specific, it is a ROS2 project.

I wanted to get rid of the compilation stage, so that the Python script can be "just" executed. Is it a legitimate approach? I do not quite understand why we need "compilation", which looks simply like copying files from one folder to another.

So, at some point I wanted to just run a Python script, by pressing a triangular "run" button in vs code IDE.

Here is the problem: if I build the project by

```
colcon build --packages-up-to my_package_name_pkg
```

then I can run a Python file.
But if "install" directory (that colcon would create) doesn't exist, I can not access some of script's functionality. For example, the following Python line

```
robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(urdf)
```

produces a

> package not found: "package 'my_package_name_pkg' not found,
> searching: ['/opt/ros/galactic']" LookupError: Could not find the
> resource 'my_doosan_pkg' of type 'packages'

As I understand, I should be able to call ROS2 functions (like xacro.process_file) from a Python file, and I do not need to compile the project for that - am I correct?

If so, how to "convince" vs code to look at project's workspace?
I tries settings.json - no effect... Where the list with ['/opt/ros/galactic'] comes from, and how to add my own directories to it?

My prime suspect is the install/setup.bash:

```
# generated from colcon_bash/shell/template/prefix_chain.bash.em

# This script extends the environment with the environment of other prefix
# paths which were sourced when this file was generated as well as all packages
# contained in this prefix path.

# function to source another script with conditional trace output
# first argument: the path of the script
_colcon_prefix_chain_bash_source_script() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    if [ -n "$COLCON_TRACE" ]; then
      echo ". \"$1\""
    fi
    . "$1"
  else
    echo "not found: \"$1\"" 1>&2
  fi
}

# source chained prefixes
# setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids determining the prefix in the sourced script
COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="/opt/ros/galactic"
_colcon_prefix_chain_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/local_setup.bash"

# source this prefix
# setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids determining the prefix in the sourced script
COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)"
_colcon_prefix_chain_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/local_setup.bash"

unset COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX
unset _colcon_prefix_chain_bash_source_script
```

But I am not sure if modifying this file is a way to go, meaning that even if it works, is it the right approach? And what exactly are the changes I have to make there?
Also, as soon as I rebuild a project, these changes will be gone...

Thank you